# Oracle - Creating chain of values and calculate cumulative count

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an oracle table DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW with below columns and sample data.
Data below shows

```
    -dmc_id ='408' there are 2109 devices which are having firmware_version='RT1' and it is the first firmware_version because image_prerequisite is null for this firmware_image.

    -dmc_id ='408' there are 40 devices which are having firmware_version='RT2' moved from "RT1" and so on.

    +-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
    device_count| dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id      |image_prerequisite|
    +-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
    | 40        | 408   |RT2              |0000        |RT1               |
    | 24        | 408   |RT3              |0000        |RT2               |
    | 18        | 408   |RT4              |0000        |RT3               |
    | 2109      | 408   |RT1              |0000        |null              |
    +-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
```

The requirement is to create the chain of firmware_versions and the count of devices moving through the chain.
For example:

```
Firmware_version movement is RT1-->RT2-->RT3-->RT4
so the count of devices moved from RT1 to RT4 is (RT1+RT2+RT3+RT4)
count of devices moved from RT2 to RT4 is (RT2+RT3+RT4)
count of devices moved from RT3 to RT4 is (RT3+RT4)
count of devices at last firmware_version is RT4



+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
cumm_device_count    | dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id |chain               | 
+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
| 82(40+24+18)       | 408   |RT2              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2        |
| 42(24+18)          | 408   |RT3              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2/RT3    |
| 18                 | 408   |RT4              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4|
| 2191(2109+40+24+18)| 408   |RT1              |0000   |null/RT1            |
+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
```

I have tried to use below query to generate the chain based on firmware_version and image_prerequisite but it is not returning the results as expected. This query is returning 28 records.

```
SELECT dmc_id, firmware_version, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(firmware_version,'/') TrackingFW
from DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW
where FIRMWARE_VERSION in ('RT1','RT2','RT3','RT4') and dmc_id='408' and charging_group_id='0000' 
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR firmware_version=image_prerequisite;
```

Please suggest query or procedure to solve this requirement.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one;

```
    select
SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(firmware_version, '/') path_,
firmware_version,
device_count,
dmc_id,
cg_id ,
(
select sum(device_count)
from  DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t2
start with t1.firmware_version=t2.firmware_version  CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version=image_prerequisite 
) sum_device
from  DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t1
start with image_prerequisite is null CONNECT BY  nocycle PRIOR   firmware_version =image_prerequisite
```

Comment: I edited and I think it works. Can you try?

Comment: Thank you ! This query worked for me :)

Comment: I have added the results that query has returned. Please help me to resolve the issue with results.

Comment: I do not understand you. which results you added and where?

Comment: I have added the details in another question because i was not able to post everything in comment. Please refer the below link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45650106/oracle-cumulative-count-using-sys-connect-by-path
Please help me to resolve this issue.