# Oracle cumulative count using SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH

Tags: oracle, plsql

When i have tried the below query on actual data it returned more number of records. Please help to resolve this issue.

Below is the actual data in table DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
device_count| dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id      |image_prerequisite|
+-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
| 40        | 408   |RT2              |0000        |RT1               |
| 24        | 408   |RT3              |0000        |RT2               |
| 18        | 408   |RT4              |0000        |RT3               |
| 2109      | 408   |RT1              |0000        |null              |
| 1         | 142   |RT1              |0000        |null              |
| 1         | 142   |RT2              |0000        |RT1               |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA1      |null              |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA2      |null              |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA3      |null              |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA4      |null              |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA5      |null              |
+-----------+-------+-----------------+------------+------------------+
```

Query that i have executed:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(firmware_version, '/') path_,
  firmware_version,
  device_count,
  dmc_id,
  charging_group_id ,
  IMAGE_PREREQUISITE,
  (SELECT SUM(device_count)
  FROM DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t2
    START WITH t1.firmware_version           =t2.firmware_version
    CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version=image_prerequisite
  ) sum_device
FROM DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t1
  START WITH image_prerequisite            IS NULL
  CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version =image_prerequisite
```

Expected Result:

```
+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
cumm_device_count    | dmc_id| firmware_version| cg_id |chain               | 
+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
| 82                 | 408   |RT2              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2        |
| 42                 | 408   |RT3              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2/RT3    |
| 18                 | 408   |RT4              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4|
| 2191               | 408   |RT1              |0000   |null/RT1            |
| 2                  | 142   |RT1              |0000   |null/RT1            |
| 1                  | 142   |RT2              |0000   |null/RT1/RT2        |
| 1                  | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA1 |null/RT1            |
| 1                  | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA2 |null/RT1            |
| 1                  | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA3 |null/RT1            |
| 1                  | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA4 |null/RT1            |
| 1                  | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA5 |null/RT1            |
+--------------------+-------+-----------------+-------+--------------------+
```

Actual returned results from query:

I have tried to use query to generate the chain based on firmware_version and image_prerequisite but it is not returning the results as expected. This query is returning more number of records.

```
/RT1    RT1 2109    408 0000000000000000        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   408 HFOTA-0000001885        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   408 HFOTA-0000000041        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   408 HFOTA-0000000441        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   408 HFOTA-0000000359        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   408 HFOTA-0000000334        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1    RT1 1   1422    0000000000000000        2990
/RT1/RT2    RT2 40  408 0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
/RT1/RT2    RT2 1   1422    0000000000000000    RT1 125
/RT1/RT2/RT3    RT3 24  408 0000000000000000    RT2 42
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4    RT4 18  408 0000000000000000    RT3 18
```

Expected results from the data stored in sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3cd9b/1

```
|/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4|  RT4       | 18 |    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|  18|
|/RT1/RT2/RT3    |  RT3       | 24 |    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|  42|
|/AP1/AP2/AP3    |  AP3       | 1  |    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|  1 |
|/RT1/RT2        |  RT2       | 40 |    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|  82|
|/AP1/AP2        |  AP2       | 2  |    408|    0000000000000000|   2    |  3 |
|/AP1            |  AP1       | 1  |    408|    0000000000000000|   1    |  4 |
|/RT1            |  RT1       |2109|    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|2191|
|/AS1            |  AS1       | 1  |    408|    0000000000000000|   24028|  1 |
|/LRA1.NOV9.01   |LRA1.NOV9.01| 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/LRA001         |  LRA001    | 9  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  9 |
|/LR1R_01        |  LR1R_01   |15  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  15|
|/APK29.2013     |APK29.2013  | 4  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  4 |
|/APK2013.29     |APK2013.29  | 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/ADR_TLRA1      |ADR_TLRA1   | 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/ADR37          |ADR37       | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/A0             |A0          | 5  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  5 |
|/36             |36          | 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/LRA1_K01       |LRA1_K01    | 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/abc            |abc         | 5  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  5 |
|/VZW_U01        |VZW_U01     | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/VZW.NOV9.01    |VZW.NOV9.01 | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/TOSS_01        |TOSS_01     | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/TK_ST001       |TK_ST001    | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/SVP01          |SVP01       | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/LRA1v1         |LRA1v1      | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/LRA2_R01       |LRA2_R01    | 2  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  2 |
|/MMY02-2013     |MMY02-2013  | 3  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  3 |
|/PP0_MR1        |PP0_MR1     | 1  |    408|    0000000000000002|   106  |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |    408|    HFOTA-0000000041|   1    |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |    408|    HFOTA-0000000334|   2    |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |    408|    HFOTA-0000000359|   1    |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |    408|    HFOTA-0000000441|   1    |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |    408|    HFOTA-0000001885|   2    |  1 |
|/RT1/RT2        |RT2         | 1  |   1422|    0000000000000000|   7    |  1 |
|/RT1            |RT1         | 1  |   1422|    0000000000000000|   7    |  2 |
```

Comment: There is `CHARGING_GROUP_ID` column in your query, but the table doesn't have such a column.

Comment: @krokodilko Please help to resolve this issue with cumulative counts.

Comment: @ASaraf, is the answer working for you or is it not? If it is, mark the answer as accepted (as is the usual behaviour on stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 0):

Solely with a trial and error over your SQL Fiddle sample data, this is the query returning your expected data:

```
SELECT SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(firmware_version, '/') path_,
  firmware_version,
  device_count,
  dmc_id,
  charging_group_id,
  IMAGE_PREREQUISITE,
  (SELECT SUM(device_count)
  FROM DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t2
  START WITH t1.firmware_version = t2.firmware_version
        and T1.dmc_id = T2.dmc_id
        and T1.charging_group_id = T2.charging_group_id
  CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version=image_prerequisite and prior dmc_id = dmc_id and prior charging_group_id = charging_group_id
  ) sum_device
FROM DM_TEMP_SUMMING_DVC_BY_FW t1
START WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR firmware_version = image_prerequisite
    and prior dmc_id = dmc_id
    and prior charging_group_id = charging_group_id
```

**Note:** Yes, the `charging_group_id` and `dmc_id` are very important for your expected result, as krokodilko correctly mentioned in his above comment.